# GIt backup ends with a rake aborted message

Tags: mysql, ruby, git, gitlab

So I am trying to do a Git backup after this script(from source): It seemed to work until a rake aborted message popped up, why is this happening what do I have to change?

```
root@gitlab-test git/gitlab$ git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production                                                                                                
Unknown option: -H                                                                                                                                                                            
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c name=value]                                                                                                                                   
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]                                                                                                                    
           [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]                                                                                                                         
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]                                                                                                                       
           <command> [<args>]                                                                                                                                                                 

root@gitlab-test git/gitlab$ git bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production                                                                                                   
error: could not open 'rake'

root@gitlab-test git/gitlab$ sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production                                                                                        
Dumping database ... 
Dumping MySQL database gitlab_production ... [DONE]
done
Dumping repositories ...
 * gitlab-admin/test ... [DONE]
 * gitlab-admin/test.wiki ...  [SKIPPED]
done
Dumping uploads ... 
rake aborted!                                                                                                                                                                                 
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - /home/git/gitlab/public/uploads                                                                                                     
/home/git/gitlab/lib/backup/files.rb:9:in `realpath'                                                                                                                                          
/home/git/gitlab/lib/backup/files.rb:9:in `initialize'                                                                                                                                        
/home/git/gitlab/lib/backup/uploads.rb:7:in `initialize'                                                                                                                                      
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:126:in `new'                                                                                                                                    
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:126:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'                                                                                                   
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'                                                                                                    
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:backup:uploads:create                                                                                                                                                    
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: What happens if you run: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create`?

Comment: It also stops at                                                                                                 Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - /home/git/gitlab/public/uploads